# Displaying Added fields in ASP MVC user table on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I used code first and added fields to the database aspnetusers and when you register everything works and saves to the DB. But I can't get the new fields to display in the view. I can only view the fields already preload with ASP. The first name is in the DB just fine not sure how to view it in the view. Intellisense won't load the added fields

```
 @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser >
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   }
  <h2>Current users</h2>

  <table class="table1" id="sort">
    <tr>
       <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Email:", "Index", new { sortOrder =    ViewBag.AddressSortParm })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("First Name:", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.StatusSortParm })
       </th>
       <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Role:", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
       </th>
       <th>
        Owner Information:
       </th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>

  @foreach (var user in Model)
  {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @user.UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @user.FirstName
        </td>
        <td>
            @user.Email
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

> MY controller

```
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var context = new IdentityDbContext();
        var users = context.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the first line of your view is referencing the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and not your view model where you added the firstname property.

```
 @model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
```

Should be changed to something like:

```
 @model IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>
```

Where ApplicationUser is something like

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then return the Users as ApplicationUser from your Action.

Or you may just need to use the ViewModel as @model where you added your custom attributes.

Comment: I tried it and it works but when I run it I get this error.                                               but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: Please update your question to show what are you returning now